# Pl-sql code showing error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am a newbie to pl-sql. the following code is generating error

```
declare
c number;
a varchar2(20);
b varchar2(20);
begin
a:='appy';
b:='1234';
select count(*) in c from userdetails where userid=a and password=b;
dbms_output.put_line('=--=-='||c);
end;
/
```

is generating the error message

```
select count(*) in c from userdetails where userid=a and password=p;
                *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-06550: line 8, column 17:
PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

My table is userdetails with 2 columns userid and password both are varchar2 type.

Comment: select .. FROM where? The parser [error] says, "I expected 'from' here, but I found 'in'. The position of the syntax error is indicated by the asterisk. The purpose of 'using [in] c' here is unclear and the question would benefit from having the goal explained.

Comment: edited the code ... that was a mistake... here now is the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select your query result into c try replace the "in" to "into" and you should also specify the table you are selecting from:

```
declare
    c number;
    a varchar2(20);
    b varchar2(20);
begin
    a:='appy';
    b:='1234';
    select count(*) into c from userdetails where userid=a and password=b;
    dbms_output.put_line('=--=-='||c);
end;
```

For more info you can read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm).

Comment: Thanks! why have to use "into" and not "in" ?

Comment: You should ask Oracle this question, this is how the langauge is built :)

Comment: In should  be used as an sql condition https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm

Comment: For one thing, `in` is already in use for [something else](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions014.htm), while `select into` is the [documented syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/selectinto_statement.htm) for putting the output of a `select` query into a variable. (To a native English speaker, `select count(*) in c` would make no sense.)